# Collection repeat is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem in Collection Repeat. Here is my controller code:

```
    .controller('RescheduleCtrl', function($scope){
    this.photos = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var w = 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
        w -= w % 5;
        var h = 150 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        h -= h % 5;
        this.photos.push({
          width: w,
          height: h,
          src: "1995"
        });
      }


    })
```

This is the code in view File:

```
 <ion-scroll direction="x" class="available-scroller">
  <div class="photo" collection-repeat="photo in photos"
     item-height="250" item-width="photo.width + 30">
 {{photo.src}}
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

I got Error: collection-repeat expected attribute collection-item-width to be a an expression that returns a number (in pixels) or percentage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not binding `photos` on HTML looking at you controller code tells that you are using `controllerAs` syntax. So if you have `ng-controller="RescheduleCtrl as reschedule"` then you can get `photos` object on html as `reschedule.photos`

**Markup**

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="available-scroller">
  <div class="photo" collection-repeat="photo in reschedule.photos"
     item-height="250" item-width="photo.width + 30">
 {{photo.src}}
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/67cc56b349124a349acb57a0740e030e?editors=101)

Comment: @NishantGarg take look at the codepen which i has created

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push something you have to add this things --> `" "`

Soo.. your script would be like this:

```
.controller('RescheduleCtrl', function($scope){
    this.photos = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var w = 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
        w -= w % 5;
        var h = 150 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        h -= h % 5;
        this.photos.push({
          "width": w,  /* Here are the edits */
          "height": h,
          "src": "1995"
        });
      }


    })
```

I hope this worked for you

Comment: Not Solved..Same Problem occurs.